# how to show array values in a for loop in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried with some Ajax success function values shows in an image gallery. I wrote this code to explode my database table column value.

```
var mystr = html.data.images;
var myarr = mystr.split("|");
console.log(myarr);
```

this code return me like this result.

```
(2) ["1562037525.jpg", "1562037525.jpg"]
0: "1562037525.jpg"
1: "1562037525.jpg"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

i want to show this image values into my image gallery src tag. i tried it like this.

```
$.each(myarr, function(index, value) {
          $('#project_img_gallery').html('<aside class="thumbnails"> <a href="#" class="selected small" data-big="/images/projects/myarr[index]">
             <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(/images/projects/'+myarr[index]+')"></div>
           </a></aside><main class="primary" style="background-image: url('/images/projects/myarr[index]');"></main>');
        });
```

but it doesn't show my array images. how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As per this,

> i want to show this image values into my image gallery src tag

You must be want this,

```
var myarr =  ["1562037525.jpg", "1562037525.jpg"];

$.each(myarr, function(index, value) {
   $('.project_img_gallery').append('<aside class="thumbnails"><a href="#" class="selected small" data-big="/images/projects/'+myarr[index]+'"> <div class = "thumbnail-image"                style = "background-image: url(/images/projects/'+myarr[index]+')"></div> </a></aside > <main class="primary" style="background-image: url(/images/projects/'+myarr[index]+')"></main>');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/doqijizeyi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer i figure out:

```
var output = '';
       output += '<aside class="thumbnails">';
       for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++){
          output += '<a href="#" class="selected small" data-big="/images/projects/'+myarr[i]+'">';
          output += '<div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(/images/projects/'+myarr[i]+')">';
          output += '</div>';
          output += '</a>';
          output += '</div>';
       }
       output += '</aside>';
       output += '<main class="primary" style="background-image: url(/images/projects/'+myarr[0]+');">';
       output += '</main>';
       $('#project_img_gallery').html(output);
```